# Hooking Android into MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

The time has come where I have to hook my app into the website's database. Unfortunately, I have absolutely zero knowledge of this subject and even more so PHP. As of now I only have to have basic functionality, which would be logging in and out of the server, and upload and download images from the user's profile on the website.

Do you all know of any well-written tutorials where I can find some of this information?

Thanks!

Comment: it's no different on android than any other system - read up about "web services".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is written in Java, you can use JDBC to connect to any database. Note that, by default, JDBC does not ship with Android's version of Java. You will need to included it with your APK.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you all know of any well-written tutorials where I can find some of
>   this information?

This is usually not my style to answer questions, but [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) you go. A very detailed tutorial. It shows you how to perform basic CRUD operations.